# How do I combine numpy "advanced indexing" with `np.newaxis`?

Tags: python, numpy

How do I combine numpy "advanced indexing" with `np.newaxis`?

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros(10)
b = np.zeros(10, dtype=np.bool_)
b[4] = True
print(a[b])  # [ 0.]
print(a[b][:, np.newaxis])  # [[ 0.]]  (works, but this is inelegant)
print(a[b, np.newaxis])  # TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

Comment: Possibly a bug with numpy?  http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2011-August/058174.html

Comment: Just does not work. Will probably work with numpy 1.8. Just chain the operation... First add the None, and then do the advanced indexing.

Comment: @seberg: Looks like the bug is nowhere on the roadmap: http://projects.scipy.org/numpy/roadmap  I don't think they know about it.

Comment: See: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/2701

Comment: @seberg:  Awesome! Thank you for your work on this issue.  Looking forward to seeing it merged soon.